# Dealing with strict rules for paper submission using LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, input, include, journal-publishing

My dear LaTeX users,

I'm quite new to Latex and as PhD student in Chemistry at want to prepare all my manuscripts in LaTeX even though my groups is not a big LaTeX user (I'm tired of Word).
Unfortunately some relevant journal in the chemistry field have some quotes like this

- For quickest processing, we prefer to receive final manuscripts from authors in Word docx format.
- Prepare only one .tex file; do not use \include or \input to incorporate another source file.
- If you are using BibTeX, do not submit .bib and .bbl files. Instead, compile your LaTeX  and copy the contents of the generated .bbl file into your .tex file.

How do you deal with them?

I think that the \include{} keyword is quite useful to change from one paper style to another one you first opinion gets rejected. And I don't even know who to deal with the third point as I usually export a .bib file from my all library in Mendeley and not only the papers that I'm citing and for that reason the .bib files is quite big.

Comment: \include is not that related to changing style, it can speed up drafts but it is trivial to replace by a single file for submission. The third point is trivial, simply do as you quote and copy the generated bbl file into your main document. The size of your bib file is not relevant, the bbl file only has the document-specific bibliography

Comment: If a journal requires Word submission, write the paper in Word. Although there are ways to convert documents, they are likely to cause more problems than writing in Word to begin with. For bibliographies, standard BibTeX is usually easier than `biblatex` (see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175)). Using `\input` and `\include` has no real advantage for article length documents.

Comment: Just FYI, MS Word has a lot of cool features... including the ability to typeset basic LaTex commands

Comment: @pushpen.paul and completely unusable when it comes to automatic bibliography handling, cross-referencing and numbering. This part is usually the worst when producing a word submission: renumbering all citations by hand in the entire paper, because attempts at using automatic system broke the document and created invisible reference stubs, broken lines and spent way too much time on trying to fix it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The journal's input requirements are very straightforward.

To fix ideas, let's assume that your document consists of four files you created yourself: `main.tex`, `sec1.tex`, `sec2.tex`, and `mybib.bib`. `mybib.bib` may contain entries that are not cited in the body of the document. Let's also assume that you know to deploy `\cite`, `\bibliographystyle`, and `\bibliography` statements and that you know how and when to run BibTeX, in addition to LaTeX, in order to create the formatted bibliography (which will be stored in `main.bbl`).

Suppose, next, that `main.tex` has the following structure:

```
\documentclass{<whatever>} % does the journal specify which document class must be used?
% preamble material, including a suitable \bibliographystyle instruction

\begin{document}
\input sec1 % including various \cite directives
\input sec2
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

The first applicable instruction is:

> Prepare only one .tex file; do not use `\include` or `\input` to incorporate another source file.

To meet this requirement, simply delete (or comment out) the two `\input` statements in `main.tex` and replace them with the *contents* of `sec1.tex` and `sec2.tex`. After these operations, `main.tex` should contain the complete LaTeX code for the document.

The only way this can fail is if the final pdf file consists of -- in addition to files with extension .tex -- graphics files (in eps, png, or pdf format, say) that are loaded via `\includegraphics` statements. If the final pdf file does rely on externally-stored graphics files, you'll simply have to include them alongside `main.tex` when you upload the files to the journal's website.

---

The second instruction is:

> If you are using BibTeX, do not submit .bib and .bbl files. Instead, compile your LaTeX and copy the contents of the generated .bbl file into your .tex file.

After running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to create the formatted bibliography and resolve all `\cite` commands, delete (or comment out) the `\bibliography` statement and  replace that statement with the *contents* of `main.bbl`. These contents will likely start with `\begin{thebibliography}{<some integer>}` and end with `\end{thebibliography}`.

You should be able to compile the complete file `main.tex` with LaTeX without any further ado. It is this version of `main.tex` that you should submit to the journal.

---

Some final comments: It's actually quite striking that the journal doesn't appear to impose any additional requirements regarding the document class, the font families, or the page layout. Consider yourself lucky! Do make life for the journal's editorial team as simple as possible by using either `article` or `report` as the document class and only the standard font families, and do make sure to engage in very little or, better still, no visual formatting. The editorial team will take note and be most appreciative.

Comment: These journals usually check correctness of references automatically. I find it strange that they want *generated* .bbl, which is much more difficult to parse and process than .bib (and may be hand-generated, or produced with completely different bibliography styles). Meanwhile, .bib file is structured data that is meant to be machine-processed. I'm dealing with such requirements quite a lot, and it strikes me as counterproductive (and possibly dangerous, as parsing and converting generated bibliography into some other format can introduce countless errors).

Comment: @orion - I actually fully agree with you. Do note, though, that my answer made no attempt to understand -- let alone justify or support -- the journal's LaTeX- and BibTeX-related requirements. All I meant to achieve was to explain how the OP might go about satisfying the journal's requirements. BTW, the purpose of the "final comments " paragraph was to encourage the OP to keep things as basic as possible (including using BibTeX and a hopefully fairly basic bibliography style). That way, if and when the paper gets accepted, the OP's additional formatting work shouldn't be too tedious.

Comment: @orion The `.bib` file may contain wide list of items, the `.bbl` file is, on the other hand, compiled for the document and contains only the references namely used within the document.

Comment: @Crowley - Thanks for this follow-up. (I agree with you too...) I think that one of the ideas that orion may have tried to express is that since the journal appears to provide no guidance as to what might constitute a preferred, or even an acceptable, bibliography style, the likelihood that the OP's  formatted bibliography will look even close to what the journal requires are rather slim, to put it charitably. If the journal's editorial staff then tries to hand-edit the contents of the `thebibliography` environment, lots of errors and inaccuracies are bound to creep in.